# Deleting multiple columns returns an error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete multiple columns using the code below:

```
Dim fileSheet as Worksheet

Set fileSheet = wb.ActiveSheet
fileSheet.Range("D:F, J:M, P:R, T:V, Z:AE,AG").EntireColumn.Delete
```

When I'm on the line of deleting the columns, it returns, `Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed` error. I don't want to delete column-by-column for it takes time executing the code.
Anyone knows what part of it I have the wrong command?

Comment: To select `AG` as well: `"D:F, J:M, P:R, T:V, Z:AE, AG:AG"`

Comment: I would also suggest that you should qualify your sheet rather than using `.ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this corrects the error ?Sorry I am from phone so I cannot test or reproduce right now.

```
fileSheet.Range("D:F, J:M, P:R, T:V, Z:AE,AG:AG").EntireColumn.Delete
```